# update UITableView based on array

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I have JSON file who's information I put in my table. I have one button for sorting my array
I can sort my array and print it with `NSLog`. How can I update my table based on my sorted array?

This is my code:

```
-(void)sortArry:(UIButton *)sender
{

    NSSortDescriptor *ageDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[ageDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [tableData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //here i have my data in nslog
    NSLog(@"%@ sort test",sortedArray);
}
```

How can I show my sortedArray in the table?

I also used

```
 [self.tableView reloadData];
```

after sorting but it didn't show the sorted table

Update:

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  
  *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in objects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell = (CustomCell *) currentObject;

            break;
        }
    }
 }


id keyValuePair;
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    keyValuePair = [self.filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


 }
else
{
    keyValuePair = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 }

cell.name.text = keyValuePair[@"name"];


return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sortedArray` is deleted when it goes out of scope at the end of your `sortArry:` method.  You need to set the property or instance variable that your UITableViewDelegate methods inspect.

Comment: Sure, if you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.

Comment: Thank you so much, I updated my question with cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

Comment: Add `self.tableData = sortedArray;` right before you call `reloadData`.

Comment: but tableData is NSMultipleArray but sortedArray is NSArray can I do that?

Comment: Use `self.tableData = [sortedArray mutableCopy];`

Comment: Also, I recommend finding a good tutorial and spending some time with it so you don't get frustrated :) these are very simple problems that you wouldn't have to ask if you went through some tutorials or a good book

Answer (score 0):

Call `[tableView reloadData];` after the array is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

`sortedArray` needs to be a property of your viewController not an instance variable of `sortArry` , so when you reload all `UITableViewdelegate` method can access its values and update.

---

```
// The array You use to populate the table
@property NSArray ArrayDataSource;
```

Change the  method signature to return the sorted array

```
-(NSArray *)sortArry
{

    NSSortDescriptor *ageDescriptor = 
                 [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[ageDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray = 
                  [tableData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //here i have my data in nslog
    NSLog(@"%@ sort test",sortedArray);

   return sortedArray;
}
```

Stored the return value in the datasource:

```
ArrayDataSource = [self.ArrayDataSource];
```

Finally reload the table

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: thanks for answer I want to have all these staff in my button when I click on my button then sort my table